# Tell gradle where to store downloaded dependencies. (Eclipse Plugin)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, gradle, dependencies, portability

I have set up a portable workspace on a thumbdrive with eclipse. The way I did it was I mounted the disk to V: and then had everything in eclipse point to it (workspaces, etc). I did this because I want to have a portable workspace I can use at school without having to download eclipse everywhere.

There is only one thing. Whenever I use a different computer, I have to refresh Gradle every time to download all the dependencies (libgdx in this case). It obviously doesn't store them anywhere on V: so how do I set gradle to download them to a location on V: so that they are also portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your projects' settings.gradle include the following:

```
getStartParameter().setProjectCacheDir(new File('/path/to/thumb/drive/workspace'))
```

This will overwrite the default cache directory of '${USER_HOME_DIRECTORY}/.gradle' to whatever you specify. The home directory is used by gradle to store dependencies.

You can also specify this on the command line:

```
gradle build --project-cache-dir "/path/to/thumb/drive/workspace"
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks! For people who view this, this is what I wrote exactly: `getStartParameter().setProjectCacheDir(new File('V:/Eclipse Workspace/Gradle'))` The reason I'm showing this is to demonstrate that spaces do work and it uses forward slashes even on Windows.